# how to implement "build your own product" feature in magento

Tags: configurable-product, bundle-product

I want to implement the "build your own product" feature for my products. I want something similar to this [`http://demo.magentocommerce.com/gaming-computer.html`](http://demo.magentocommerce.com/gaming-computer.html) with file upload facility. Any idea how to go about it?

Comment: So just see the product in backend how magento create this product?

Comment: You need to create bundle product. REFER: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-bundled-product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with bundle products, just like the demo does.

You should find the same product in the back-end to see how it's built, [here](http://demo-admin.magentocommerce.com/), but for some reason it's not there anymore. I think someone deleted all the products.

Anyway the admin demo should reset after a few hours.
 If you still cannot find it:

- download the '[sample data](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download)',
- install a new instance of magento with sample data
- you should be able to find it in the backend.